# laravel show "stats" ordered by date and counts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I want to show the stats of visitors on my website,

What I have:

> AdminClontroller

```
public function index()
    {

        $select_stats = DB::table('visitor')->whereBetween('visit_date', array(date('Y-m-01'), date('Y-m-t')))->get();

        $month = date('m');

        $get_count = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT count(*) FROM visitor WHERE MONTH(date) = $month GROUP BY DAY(date)"));


        foreach($select_stats as $statics) {

       //change our object to an array
       $statics = array();
        }


    return View::make('admin.home.index')->with('stats', $select_stats)/*->with('count', $get_count)*/;

    }
```

> database model

[image: database model]

> View

```
var visitors = [
@foreach($stats as $stat)
                ['{{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime($stat->date)) }}', 55],
@endforeach
            ];
```

I want to get a stat like this:

[image: stats]

But with the correct data from the database.

I want that I get the count of all IP's that visited my site on day 'x', and that for a month long.

So: on 2015-04-14 I got 20 visits, that is what I want to get, but looped in my template.

I hope you guys do understand me.

Kindest regards,

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer... I need it very soon...